# wordpress loop with additional elements

Tags: php, wordpress

I created post template for a specific category, where are thumbnail, title, excerpt and I added additional div to the template with custom content, which will be generated automatically, let it be div class = "custom". I also created a loop on the blog page which shows all post from this specific category. I know how to show thumbnail, title, excerpt, but don't know how to show .custom. How should I create this loop? Thank you

```
<?php
        if ( have_posts() ) :
          query_posts('cat=1');   
          while (have_posts()) : the_post();  
        ?>
        <div class = "programs-flex-item">
          <div class = "programs-flex-item__title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
          <div class = "programs-flex-item__image"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
          <div class = "programs-flex-item__excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
          <div class = "custom">HERE IS CUSTOM CONTENT!!!</div>

        </div>
         <?php 
          endwhile; 
          endif;
        wp_reset_query();                
      ?>
```

Comment: what do you mean by  `CUSTOM CONTENT` here? what you want to add as `CUSTOM CONTENT` there exactly?

Comment: @AlivetoDie it will be random html content generated with js on post template (single.php for example)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to store custom post values are metadata or post meta. It's a basic key, value pair which can be expanded by using custom post fields plugins (choose any you like). In code you can use

```
get_post_meta();
```

to get the metas for a post. Link [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/). Also check this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38530/most-efficient-way-to-get-posts-with-postmeta/254620) for more information

Comment: ok, but if I don't want to have permission to edit this field, I just want to have a variable on my post template that I can use in loop